# Why do the selected contacts not appear in the textview?

Tags: android, textview, android-contacts

I am creating a multiple choice layout for contact list. I successfully pick the contacts. However, instead of displaying the contact name in text view,it appear as String value. I just want the contact name to appear in TextView not the String values.

I got 2 classes. One class is to pick contact. While the other class is for browsing and selecting the contacts.

Selected Contact Activity

```
package com.droidnova.android.samples;

 import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.database.Cursor;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.provider.Contacts.People;
  import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.Button;


   public class SelectContact extends Activity {
 private static final int PICK_CONTACT = 0;
 private Button btnPick;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.button);

        btnPick = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        btnPick.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener());


    }
    @Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Cursor contact = getContentResolver().query(data.getData(), null, null, null, null);
                contact.moveToFirst();
                String name = contact.getString(contact.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People.NAME));


        }

    }
       }
    private class MyOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
     @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
         startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK),PICK_CONTACT);
  }
  }
}
```

Contacts Activity

```
package com.droidnova.android.samples;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.zip.Inflater;
 import android.app.ListActivity;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
 import android.database.Cursor;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.provider.Contacts.People;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Adapter;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.ListAdapter;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 public class Contacts extends ListActivity {
ListView list;
TextView Selection;



private static String[] PROJECTION = new String[]
{
    People._ID,
    People.NAME,
    People.NUMBER,
};

  @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    list=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(People.CONTENT_URI, 
            PROJECTION, null, null, null);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,
            cursor,new String[]{People.NAME},new int[]{android.R.id.text1});

    getListView().setChoiceMode(2);
   setListAdapter(adapter);
    Selection = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.selection);
   }
  @Override

  protected void onListItemClick(ListView parent,View v,int position,long id){
  Selection.setText("");
  SparseBooleanArray chosen = parent.getCheckedItemPositions();
  for(int i=0;i<chosen.size();i++)
  {
          Log.d("Selection", "index:"+i+";key:"+chosen.keyAt(i) +";value:"+chosen.valueAt(i)
                  +";"+PROJECTION[chosen.keyAt(i)]);

          if(chosen.valueAt(i)){
              Selection.append(PROJECTION[chosen.keyAt(i)]+"");
          }

      }
  }
```

}

---

This is my logcat:

```
12-02 03:10:49.840: INFO/ActivityManager(53): Starting activity: Intent {    act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.droidnova.android.samples/.SelectContact }
12-02 03:10:49.930: INFO/ActivityManager(53): Start proc com.droidnova.android.samples for activity com.droidnova.android.samples/.SelectContact: pid=715 uid=10025 gids={1015}
12-02 03:10:49.930: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(709): Shutting down VM
12-02 03:10:49.930: DEBUG/dalvikvm(709): DestroyJavaVM waiting for non-daemon threads to exit
12-02 03:10:49.940: DEBUG/dalvikvm(709): DestroyJavaVM shutting VM down
12-02 03:10:49.940: DEBUG/dalvikvm(709): HeapWorker thread shutting down
12-02 03:10:49.940: DEBUG/dalvikvm(709): HeapWorker thread has shut down
12-02 03:10:49.940: DEBUG/jdwp(709): JDWP shutting down net...
12-02 03:10:49.940: INFO/dalvikvm(709): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
12-02 03:10:49.960: DEBUG/dalvikvm(709): VM cleaning up
12-02 03:10:49.990: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(709): ERROR: thread attach failed
12-02 03:10:50.030: DEBUG/dalvikvm(709): LinearAlloc 0x0 used 639500 of 5242880 (12%)
12-02 03:10:50.230: DEBUG/ddm-heap(715): Got feature list request
12-02 03:10:50.910: INFO/ActivityManager(53): Displayed activity com.droidnova.android.samples/.SelectContact: 1000 ms (total 1000 ms)
12-02 03:10:51.921: INFO/ActivityManager(53): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.PICK cmp=com.droidnova.android.samples/.Contacts }
12-02 03:10:52.441: INFO/ActivityManager(53): Displayed activity com.droidnova.android.samples/.Contacts: 431 ms (total 431 ms)
12-02 03:10:53.521: DEBUG/Selection(715): index:0;key:0;value:true;_id
12-02 03:10:54.391: DEBUG/Selection(715): index:0;key:0;value:true;_id
12-02 03:10:54.391: DEBUG/Selection(715): index:1;key:1;value:true;name
12-02 03:10:54.841: DEBUG/Selection(715): index:0;key:0;value:true;_id
12-02 03:10:54.851: DEBUG/Selection(715): index:1;key:1;value:true;name
12-02 03:10:54.851: DEBUG/Selection(715): index:2;key:2;value:true;number
12-02 03:10:57.531: DEBUG/dalvikvm(220): GC freed 43 objects / 2024 bytes in 77ms
12-02 03:11:24.040: DEBUG/Selection(715): index:0;key:0;value:false;_id
12-02 03:11:24.040: DEBUG/Selection(715): index:1;key:1;value:true;name
12-02 03:11:24.050: DEBUG/Selection(715): index:2;key:2;value:true;number
12-02 03:11:25.120: DEBUG/Selection(715): index:0;key:0;value:false;_id
12-02 03:11:25.120: DEBUG/Selection(715): index:1;key:1;value:false;name
12-02 03:11:25.130: DEBUG/Selection(715): index:2;key:2;value:true;number
12-02 03:11:25.670: DEBUG/Selection(715): index:0;key:0;value:false;_id
12-02 03:11:25.680: DEBUG/Selection(715): index:1;key:1;value:false;name
12-02 03:11:25.680: DEBUG/Selection(715): index:2;key:2;value:false;number
12-02 03:11:26.641: DEBUG/Selection(715): index:0;key:0;value:true;_id
12-02 03:11:26.641: DEBUG/Selection(715): index:1;key:1;value:false;name
12-02 03:11:26.651: DEBUG/Selection(715): index:2;key:2;value:false;number
12-02 03:11:27.171: DEBUG/Selection(715): index:0;key:0;value:true;_id
12-02 03:11:27.181: DEBUG/Selection(715): index:1;key:1;value:true;name
12-02 03:11:27.181: DEBUG/Selection(715): index:2;key:2;value:false;number
12-02 03:49:00.191: DEBUG/dalvikvm(53): GC freed 17933 objects / 880976 bytes in 150ms
12-02 04:22:34.131: DEBUG/dalvikvm(102): GC freed 11675 objects / 524064 bytes in 81ms
12-02 04:38:00.181: DEBUG/dalvikvm(53): GC freed 20167 objects / 943152 bytes in 147ms
```

Comment: What do u mean by "String value" here.. if you can show logcat o/p would be helpful to help u.

Comment: Ouh.Someone please help me....

Answer (score 0):

try this..i am using this code for get Email and Name from Contact. use this code as per your Requirement

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {        


                   if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
                    {
                       if(requestCode==CONTACT_PICKER_EMAIL)
                       {
                           Cursor cursor = null;
                            String email = "";
                            try 
                            {
                                Uri result = data.getData();
                                Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "Got a contact result: "
                                        + result.toString());

                                // get the contact id from the Uri
                                String id = result.getLastPathSegment();

                                // query for everything email
                                cursor = getContentResolver().query(Email.CONTENT_URI,
                                        null, Email.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[] { id },
                                        null);

                                int emailIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Email.DATA);

                                // let's just get the first email
                                if (cursor.moveToFirst())
                                {
                                    email = cursor.getString(emailIdx);                                
                                    txtconfirmBy.setText(email);
                                } 
                                else 
                                {
                                    Log.w(DEBUG_TAG, "No results");
                                }
                            } 
                            catch (Exception e) 
                            {
                                Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "Failed to get email data", e);
                            } 
                            finally 
                            {
                                if (cursor != null) 
                                {
                                    cursor.close();
                                }                      

                            }     

                       }
                       else if (requestCode==CONTACT_PICKER_NAME) 
                       {
                           Uri contactData = data.getData();
                            Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                            if (c.moveToFirst()) 
                            {                       
                                String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People.DISPLAY_NAME));
                                txtparticipant.setText(name);           

                            }      
                     }

                    }




    }
```

**Send Request for get Details like this**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CONTACT_PICKER_EMAIL);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);           
            startActivityForResult(intent,CONTACT_PICKER_NAME);
```